# Adding own value in SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy

I'm currently extracting data from an xml file and copying it to store in the database. Is there a way for me to add my own values during SqlBulkCopy? I want to add my own value itemsTotalPrice as I want to calculated the total price of the items but can't get it to work. How do I get around this?

```
 DataTable sourceData = ds.Tables["Invoice"];
 sourceData.Columns.Add("itemsTotalPrice", typeof(System.Decimal));
 sourceData.Columns.Add("invoiceTotal", typeof(System.Decimal));
 sqlConn.Open();
       using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbc = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn))
            {
                sqlbc.DestinationTableName = "Invoice";
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("invoiceDate", "invoiceDate");
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("orderID", "orderID");
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("sellerID", "sellerID");
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("itemsTotalPrice", itemsTotalPrice);
                //sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("shippingCharges", "shippingCharges");
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("invoiceTotal", "invoiceTotal");
                sqlbc.WriteToServer(sourceData);
            }
```

Comment: put your full code and error?

Comment: @DenishParvadia I've edited and added the full code

Comment: plz put your error message?

Comment: @DenishParvadia There were 2 error messages pertaining to this."Error 1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyColumnMappingCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid arguments" and "Error 2: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'string'"

Comment: first convert itemtotalprice. Convert.ToDecimal(itemsTotalPrice);

Comment: @DenishParvadia done, no changes in error

Comment: i have put reference code ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by loading the Xml into a `DataTable`, modify values in columns according to your choice, and try use `WriteToServer`.

Comment: I actually already had a datable and writetoserver. i'd edited the code in my qns, but how do I modify the values so that I can add my own value?

Comment: man, if you have a `DataTable` you can do what ever you want with it.Iterate over rows, change column values.Is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

reference code.

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {


            try
            {
                if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" || FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
                {
                    if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength >= 0)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName);

                        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/DownloadedExcelFilesOp4/myfile" + fileExt));
                        if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength == 0)
                        {
                            lblMsg.Text = fun.UploadStatus;
                            lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        }
                        else
                            lblMsg.Text = fun.UploadStatus;
                        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", Server.MapPath(@"~\DownloadedExcelFilesOp4\myfile" + fileExt));// + "\\" + FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
                        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                        {
                            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(("Select [Customer] ,[InvoiceDate] , [InvoiceNo] , [CustomerPo],[SoLine] ,[VendorName] ,[Category] ,[Item] ,[PickQty] ,[Price] ,[PriceExtentio]  FROM [Sheet1$]"), connection);
                            connection.Open();
                            using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
                                {
                                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TempExamQuation4Master";
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Customer", "Customer");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("InvoiceDate", "InvoiceDate");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("InvoiceNo", "InvoiceNo");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomerPo", "CustomerPo");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SoLine", "SoLine");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VendorName", "VendorName");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Categor", "Categor");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Item", "Item");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PickQty", "PickQty");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Price", "Price");
                                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PriceExtentio", "PriceExtentio");

                                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: thank you very much, although it still wasn't enough able to help me answer